# Photoswipe (mobile) - image selection (photoswipe open) stops working from time to time

Tags: javascript, html, css, photoswipe

This is a shot in the dark, but I'm having an issue with Photoswipe (v4.1.3) using the multi-gallery [implementation](https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM/?editors=1010). The touch-to-open-gallery on mobile stops working after 2-3 touch-and-close's. What I have to do is to move the gallery away from view and bring it back into view to enable touch-to-open-gallery.

In Chrome's DevTool, the mobile simulator works fine. It's just that when I use Photoswipe on an iPhone, I have this issue.

Again, a shot in the dark... If you would like me to provide code snippets, I'd be happy to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if anyone sees this in the future, you'll understand that on mobile (true mobile), opening an image in a Photoswipe gallery can be a nightmare IF there is a hash in your base URL.

e.g.:
`https://myurl.com/#about` - Nightmare
`https://myurl.com/` - OK

I solved this issue by simply setting `history` in `options` to `false`. That's it. Now you can be fancy and only target history manipulation for mobile, because having `history: true` for desktop IS a nice feature.

```js
// stuff above

var $pswp = $('.pswp')[0],
  options = {
    index: $(this).parent('figure').index(),
    bgOpacity: 0.85,
    showHideOpacity: true,
    history: false,  // set this to false - it's true by default
  };

// stuff below
```